# How to make .vue files work in VS2019 Net Code 3.1

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, visual-studio-2019

Hopefully someone can help me out with getting .vue files work in VS 2019 Net Core 3.1.
(creating vue components with template,script and style in 1 file called [name].vue)

I spend hours (days) to read about it etc. but it does not bring me anywhere.
Watched several youtube examples about Vue, about Vue components, followed online instructions and tried few examples I downloaded from github.
(for example https://medium.com/@alexandre.malavasi/update-template-vue-js-asp-net-core-3-1-visual-studio-2019-caf13caab34b)

Unfortunatly none of the example makes clear what I want, and it should be very simple!
None of the downloaded examples do work well and need updates or chanes I do not understand.

So....it probably (and of course) is my lack of knowledge and experience about these two subjects but hopefully someone knows or has a simple basic working example of this for VS 2019.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a little clearer in what you're trying to do? You're trying to make vue files load correctly in Visual Studio 2019? You're trying to run them through Visual Studio? Some clarity would help.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. I am trying to convert the .vue files with webpack to files which can be used by the browser. This step does not generate files at the moment but gives me lot of errors due to missing or wrong versions of Babel, vue-loader etc. Showing and solving the errors via stackoverflow would not be good, so I wondered if someone has a simple basic working example or instruction which I can use to compare with my solution.

Comment: Note: The example project from medium.com (thnx @alexandre.malavasi ) as I mentioned in my post, is now working well. Still not in my own project but hopefully I can make that work asap.

Comment: Update: ok, now it works. Seems that I had installed to much packages which caused errors (about missing modules,depencies etc). I cleaned de package.json and only added the packages from the working example project. Now it works fine!